# how to remove All child element in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone tell me how to remove all child element of parent div.

Suppose there is ul element. ul has 3 childs. so i want to remove this child and redraw new childs. so that's why i need to remove all child of ul.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't sound like a particularly Angular-y thing to do -- you're thinking too low-level.

If you have a list of stuff you want to display:

```
$scope.myStuff = [42, 35, 76];
```

you can do it with something like

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in myStuff"> {{ x }} is a cool number </li>
</ul>
```

Then just update `$scope.myStuff` and angular will take care of the redrawing automatically.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

See http://jsfiddle.net/H3sC2/1/ for an example.

Comment: @priyashivale You gotta give more info than that. What's not working? You're updating some list in your controller but the html element with `ng-repeat` isn't updating on its own? Post your code (preferably a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/))