# Remove Element from DOM before getting rendered with an angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I'm looking for a way to build a direcive for the following demands:

- should remove elements based on the passed attribute value
- should remove before getting rendered
- should remove all child elements
- should visually work like `ng-if` in combination with `ng-bind`

Or to say it in another way: the elements should be removed after the initial page load and before the element get rendered, so that the user will not see the element "blinking". Is there a way without using `ng-bind`?

`ng-bind` is not always very helpful:

```
<parent my-directive>
    <child ng-bind="Hi"></child>
</parent>
```

---

```
.parent {
     background-color: red;
     padding: 50px;
}
```

Thanks a lot & best regards!

Comment: I guess you can do it in a link function

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: When using `ng-if` its blinking for milliseconds:
http://codepen.io/codelabr/full/jbJVea/

afaik `ng-if` is using the `link` function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my assumption is correct, you can use `ng-cloak` to stop the blinking caused by the angular compiler.

```
<parent ng-cloak>
    <child ng-bind="Hi"></child>
</parent>
```

**Explanation**

All elements which contains `ng-cloak` will be hide initially and it will be visible only after completing angular's compilation.

If you add `ng-cloak` to your `body` tag, then all page will be hide and be visible only after angular's compilation.

**Update**

```
<header ng-cloak ng-app>
  <h1 ng-cloak ng-if="false" style="background-color: red">  
    <span>TEST</span>
  </h1> 
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your idea in a MWE: http://codepen.io/codelabr/pen/ojVYQK || Isn't `ng-cloak` only working for expressions but not for directives?

Comment: I've updated my MWE. It's still blinking, isn't it? :(

Comment: Found the answer for the `ng-cloak` problem: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jun/02/AngularJs-ngcloak-Problems-on-large-Pages#Addtheng-cloakStylesmanually

Answer (score 0):

ng-bind is the perfect way to bind element at run time.For more spotlight on this
visit [how to remove All child element in Angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781025/how-to-remove-all-child-element-in-angular-js).